# How to execute a command from a virtual environment using `crontab` or `gnome-terminal`

Tags: python, virtualenv, cron, gnome-terminal, virtualenvwrapper

When I want to work on a virtual environment with *virtualenv(1.8.2)* and *virtualenvwrapper(3.6)* I just run `workon my_project`.  I am however **unable to execute a command from a virtual environment using `crontab` or `gnome-terminal`**:

**Examples:**

`* * * * * workon my_project && python task.py`

This is'nt executed. (The task writes to a file)

or

`gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c \"workon my_project;python task.py;exec bash\""`
This just shows `bash: workon: command not found` and then executes the program from the system environment. Check [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/05/25/bash-script-to-open-a-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-on-linux-start-up/) for more info about this command.

### Edit

@Zaar Hai: To initiate `virtualenvwrapper` this in my `/home/myusername/.bashrc`:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
```

So I tried this command:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c \"export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs;source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh;export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME;export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true;source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/activate;exec bash\""
```

But I still get that same output as I posted in your comment.

Comment: I think this question fits on both `stackoverflow` as `superuser` though: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. (software tools commonly used by programmers)

Comment: Forget about `workon` and `activate`. Use the absolute python path of your virtualenv's python and get the task done easier and safer. Like: `/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python task.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through crontab:

```
0 10 * * * env -i bash -c 'export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon my_project && python task.py'
```

Through gnome terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon my_project && python task.py " '
```

Better of all just create a runme.sh script:

```
#/bin/sh
set -e
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon my_project
exec python task.py
```

And run this script through gnome terminal / crontab.

Comment: This probably works when you merely have `virtualenv` installed. But I also use virtualenvwrapper, so this is what I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.`

Comment: Btw, check the edit of my original post for more information.

Comment: I also use `virtualenvwrapper` and barely sourcing `activate` is enough. Do you have any custom hooks for your `virtualenv`. Lets simplify command to this: `env -i bash -c 'export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/activate && python ...'"`

Comment: The problem is that you use $VAR inside **double** quotes - it gets evaluated by shell that executes the whole command, and not by the internal bash. You need to use single quotes to prevent launching shell from evaluating variables inside the string.

Comment: Running `env -i bash -c 'export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/activate && workon my_project && python task.py'` **works perfectly**! However I don't know how I should combine it in my `gnome-terminal` command. I tried `gnome-terminal --tab -e 'env -i bash -c \'export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/activate;exec bash\''`, but this just opens a prompt. I think I'm not properly formatting this, any ideas?

Comment: `gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "export..."'` You do not need to `exec` bash in the end. `exec` python if you really want to exec.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the latest "what works". Also no need to both sourcing activation script and running `workon ...`. They are do the save thing mostly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22899/discussion-between-zaar-hai-and-bentley4)